# Автодополнение для D в VS Code

Tags: intellisense, d

Использую расширение **code-d**. Для стандартной библиотеки автодополнение работает, но вот для устанавливаемых модулей нет. Тот же vibe-d. А также, спокойно можно написать вызов несуществующего метода или подобную ошибку, и при этом как ошибка оно не будет подсвечиваться.

Это я что-то не правильно настроил, или это просто сырая экосистема у языка?
Кроме **VS Сode** пробовал **Dexed**, но он будто-бы в разы хуже.